# Добавить ряд html таблицы JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте.
Проблема...
Есть HTML таблица:

```
<table id="generator_t">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3">GENERATOR</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>пос</td>
        <td>пос</td>
        <td>пос</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Нужно через JavaScript, добавить tr с тремя ячейками перед последним tr
Как это возможно реализовать?
Спасибо.

Comment: Используете jQuery? или нужен чистый js?

Comment: нужен чистый JS

Comment: А почему сам не можешь сделать? Ты вообще пытался хоть что-то найти или сделать?

Comment: Да, я нашел как в конец добавить, но не в нужное место...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В принципе, в коде комментарии есть.
Но вот на [codepen](http://codepen.io/VostokSisters/pen/LxrGGj?editors=1010) форматирование более понятное.

```js
// Создаем переменные, на которые ссылаемся
var tbodyOfTable = document.querySelector('#generator_t tbody');
var listOfTr = tbodyOfTable.children;
// Генерируем новый элемент
var newTr = document.createElement('tr');
newTr.innerHTML = '<td>2</td><td>2</td><td>2</td>';
// Вставляем элемент по кнопке `input`
document.querySelector('input').onclick = function() {
  tbodyOfTable.insertBefore(newTr, listOfTr[(listOfTr.length - 1)]);
}
```

```html
<table id="generator_t">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="3">GENERATOR</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>пос</td>
    <td>пос</td>
    <td>пос</td>
  </tr>
</table>


<input type='button'>
```

Comment: Спасибо, огромное)))

Answer (score 0):

Добавляется не в то место, потому что в таблице, на самом деле, внутри все обернуто ещё в элемент **tbody**:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Посмотри в отладчике.
Добавлять можно примерно так:

```js
var table = document.getElementById('generator_t');
var tbody = table.children[0]

var tr = document.createElement('tr');
var tdValues = [
  'Значения', 'трех', 'ячеек'
];

tr.innerHTML = '<td>' + tdValues[0] + '</td> <td>' + tdValues[1] + '</td> <td>' + tdValues[2] + '</td>';

tbody.appendChild(tr)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="generator_t">
      <tr>
          <th colspan="3">GENERATOR</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
          <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>пос</td>
          <td>пос</td>
          <td>пос</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Нужно вставлять перед последним tr.